# How can I archive some sort of graduated overlay from a video to a still image

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem, that I don't know how to make a gradient like an overlay between an image and a Video. The idea is, that when you scroll down the page the Video, which was the main background on the main page will fade to white. Basically, the video should fade away revealing a white canvas for other images, text iframes, etc. How can I do such a thing?

This is the sort of look I'm going for
https://www.adlogica.ch/
when you scroll down the background video fades to white.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated and I have attached some code for the video. (The code for the video is working fine I just can't figure out how to fade it when you are scrolling down)

```
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: You would need to place an element below the video which contains a gradient from transparent to white. This could either be an image with transparency (png) or a styled div. Where do you need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could something like this work?
Just need to replace the image with the video.
You can generate the gradient using this useful [tool](https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
  color: #212121;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 98%;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
width: 100%;
position: relative;
box-sizing: content-box;
}

.content div {
  margin: .25em 6em 6em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya:ital,wght@0,600;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
<div class="img-bg">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1439405326854-014607f694d7?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
</div>
<div class="content">
<div>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis ex tortor. Donec non pulvinar urna. Phasellus at placerat urna. Ut suscipit tortor eget neque egestas, vel aliquam turpis dapibus. Suspendisse in aliquam arcu. Sed ultricies sollicitudin justo, a pretium enim sodales sed. Aenean in porta eros. Vestibulum imperdiet orci suscipit, condimentum sem id, ultrices lorem.

Fusce at malesuada ex. Sed ac porttitor dui, sed pulvinar dolor. In pulvinar ultrices nisi nec tempor. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque eleifend vulputate dolor, ac commodo velit porta volutpat. Phasellus id fringilla justo. Suspendisse pretium turpis sed convallis suscipit. Maecenas velit purus, condimentum sit amet tortor et, condimentum dignissim ipsum. Aenean consequat libero in purus pulvinar condimentum.</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @LS_ mentions, you can do this by creating a gradient using CSS. However, the site you linked to uses a [large semi-transparent gradient image](https://static.wixstatic.com/media/1e47b2_5933ee74ead1423ea0746d23c30f1b4e%7Emv2.png/v1/fill/w_406,h_1080,al_t,q_90/1e47b2_5933ee74ead1423ea0746d23c30f1b4e%7Emv2.webp) (white at the bottom, more transparent toward the top), which is also an option:

[image]

I'm not sure if there are modern reasons to prefer images over CSS. CSS gradients are the the newer option.